# syntax to send list of models from a view to controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, view, model

Im searching for the syntax (in c#)  for sending from a form with multiple inputs, multiple model inatances.
For example , lets say i have a model that holds two strings and a form in the view that has pairs of texboxes, i want to create a model from each pair of textboxes and send the collection to the controller.

How can it be done? Thanka.

Comment: MVC is a language-independent architectural design pattern. Not a framework or language.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC framework? If so, then question should be tagged a such.

Answer (score 0):

You only can submit one model to a controller. However the model can contain lists of objects. For example;

```
  public class myModel
  {
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Wong { get; set; }
    public List<text_boxes> TextBoxes { get; set; }
  }

  public class text_boxes
  {
    public name { get; set; }
    public blah { get; set; }
  }
```